# React router is taking me to the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have a nav bar that has Home and About links , I'm trying to make a router that goes to About page when I click on about link and goes to home when I click on Home link , but I don't know why either I click at home or about , It takes me to Home page

this is App.js file :

```
<Router>
<Box>
<Navbar />
<Home />
<Routes>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/about" component={AboutUs}/>
</Routes>
</Box>
</Router>
```

and this is Home.js file :

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
    <FirstSection />
    <SecondSection />
    <ThirdSection />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is About file :

```
function AboutUs() {
  return (
    <div>AboutUs</div>
  )
}
```

and lastly this is the nav bar :

```
<a href="/">
            <MenuButton>
                Home
            </MenuButton>
            </a>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
        <a href="/about">
            <MenuButton>
                About us 
            </MenuButton>
            </a>
```

Comment: Use the `Link` component instead of an anchor tag. And if you are using `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components should use the `element` prop, i.e. `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 <Menu>
<Lint to="/">
  <MenuButton>
     Home
   </MenuButton>
 </Lint >
   </Menu>
   <Menu>
      <Link to="/about">
        <MenuButton>
           About us 
        </MenuButton>
      </Link >
   </Menu>
```

If your livestock router version is 6, you should do this:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}>
        <Route path="/about" element={<AboutUs/>}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `<Link />` component on the `<NavBar />` component instead of `<a>` tags.

Thus your code should look like

```
<Menu>
    <Link to="/home">
        <MenuButton>
            Home
        </MenuButton>
    </Link>
</Menu>
<Menu>
     <Link to="/about">
         <MenuButton>
              About us 
         </MenuButton>
      </Link>
</Menu>
```

For more info about the `<Link />` component you can read through the [react-router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params).

Comment: There is an improvement , Thanks to you Instead of only displaying Home only when clicking on home or about, now It displays Home and About page together , I guess maybe I can do anything to make it only render one of them ?

Comment: You could add a `<Switch />` from `react-router` in order to just render one path or one `<Route />`, for more info read through the [`<Switch /> docs`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)